# 3 finger tap on word to show spanish-english translation of word

Tags: macbook-pro, multi-touch, dictionary

3 finger tap triggers the English dictionary, but it only works to explain English words in English.

Is there any way to change a 3 finger tap to show the translation of an English word into Spanish, or a Spanish word into English?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to add the necessary modules to Dictionary.app, e.g. see

http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2011/12/more-dictionaries-for-dictionaryapp.html

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer, Tom! Can you please summarize the contents of the link? Links have a tendency to disappear over time, leaving an answer that is not useful for those who  may find your answer down the road. Thank you!

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaand, the link is broken. (and it's the responder's own blog).